# Angularjs select option value as default

Tags: angularjs

How to select the type1 value which is 3 from the template

```
<select   name="type1" id="type1"  placeholder="test" ng-model="project.type1" >
   <option value="1" >VER</option>
   <option value="3">Task</option>
</select>

app.controller('Test',function($scope){
  $scope.project.type1 = "3";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select   name="type1" id="type1"  placeholder="test" ng-model="project.type1" >
   <option value="1" ng-selected="project.type1 == 1">VER</option>
   <option value="3" ng-selected="project.type1 == 3>Task</option>
</select>
```

It'd be automatic though if you just use `ng-options` directive on your `<select>` instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: @Rajeev That's great. Consider upvoting/accepting the answer if yout issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
$scope.project.type1 = "3";
```

in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the `project` variable as an object before adding `type1` property:

```
app.controller('Test',function($scope){
    $scope.project = {};
    $scope.project.type1 = 3;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gmLhdamf/